# Is there a programming language other than Java, C#, and Go which includes null with its static object types?

Tags: programming-languages, type-systems, null, static-typing

I was reading the excellent book by Axel Raushmayer, Tackling TypeScript.

In [this section of Chapter 7](https://exploringjs.com/tackling-ts/ch_typescript-essentials.html#by-default-undefined-and-null-are-not-included-in-types), the author makes the interesting claim

> In many programming languages, null is part of all object types. For example, whenever the type of a variable is String in Java, we can set it to null and Java won’t complain.

I am a little confused by the claim of “many” here. Exactly how many languages do this? C++ doesn’t, as pointer types are explicit (a `string` can never be null, but a `string*` can have the value `nullptr`). Neither does C. Neither do Rust, Swift, TypeScript, etc. Certainly all dynamically languages do not, as they have a Null or NoneType or similar. C# does because of its Java ancestry, and Go has `nil` for its reference types.

The way I understand the programming language landscape, it was Java that introduced this version of the billion dollar mistake, though they may have stolen it from an early Algol. And I don’t believe it is common at all.

Am I correct that this claim is misleading at best and that it is only Java (and C# and Go?) among modern static programming languages that conflate nulls with object types? If the claim is correct, then there is much about language type systems I don't understand, and was hoping the community here could come up with a list of popular languages for which this situation holds.

(I'm asking on software engineering stack exchange rather than the computer science stack exchange since the problem of having null values in static object types has, we all know, many ramifications for engineering correct and secure code. Regarding what I have tried so far, I've looked at all the languages mentioned above, as well as Julia, the ML family of languages, and more.)

### CLARIFICATION

In response to some comments, I think I need to be more clear about the question. The question is independent of value or reference semantics (copy vs. sharing), and independent of primitive or non primitive types, and independent of mutability vs. immutability.

The language Java automatically, implicitly, adds an extra member to many types. For example, when giving a variable a type constraint such as:

```
String supervisor;
```

we can assign the value `null` to the variable `supervisor`. Now I think it is reasonable to take the point of view that `null` is not a string: it does not have a length, it can not be reversed, etc. In fact the very use of `null` is to indicate there is *no* supervisor. So including `null` *in the type* is clunky at best and confusing at worst (and yes, I know about `NaN`). I totally get that it's here because it is "easy," and this is *exactly* what Tony Hoare admitted in his famous Billion Dollar Mistake mea culpa.

Now languages with optionals built-in from the ground up (Swift, Rust, Haskell) and those with explicit pointers (C, C++), would never, ever allow anything other than an actual string to be assigned to a variable constrained to type string. Yet Java does. I am asking whether anyone knows of any other languages that do. I do not suspect there are many, that's all. :)

Comment: I am truly baffled by this question. To me it is obvious on its face that C and C++ have null pointers. Perhaps you are making a distinction between a null pointer and some sort of null object type? I don't understand.

Comment: I think this question uses the term "object type" for what I usually know as "reference type". And @JohnWu, as you surely know, C++ reference variables (opposed to pointers) are not allowed to be null.

Comment: @JohnWu In C++ constraining a variable to have type `string`, say, means it can only hold values of the `string` type. It is impossible to assign `nullptr` to such a variable. For example `string s = nullptr;` is a type error in C++ (you have to say `string* p = nullptr;`), while `String s = null;` is perfectly fine in Java. C++ does is right by making `string` and `string*` completely different types. Java is weird IMHO by making `String` refer to the union of strings and the null value. Hope that clears it up!

Comment: Thanks Ray, that makes sense in hindsight. I guess I have grown too accustomed to `LPSTR` and `BSTR`!

Comment: @RayToal the ciloarison is inacurate as  typescript uses objects with a reference semantic and C++ a value semantic. You must compare comparable things. In C++, the equivalent of a java (or javascript, if it weren't about dynamic typing)  object would be a  pointer. Null is not an issue here.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Go but based on this, it has `nil` which seems to work roughly the same way as `null` in Java.  Can you explain what difference you see?

Comment: Woops you are right about Go, I should not have included that. I will update the question. Thank you!

Comment: @RayToal: the equivalent of a Java `String x` in C++ is a `shared_ptr<string> x` (much more similar than `string *x` or `string &x`,  not a `string x`). And `shared_ptr` variables can be null. C# also distingusihes between reference types and value types. reference types could be null in the past. but starting with C#10,  even reference type variables `T x` cannot be null by default unless one allows them to be explicitly by declaring them as `T? x` (this is a feature which can be switched off for backwards compatibility).

Comment: @DocBrown, great points. yes Java `String` is like C++ `shared_ptr<string>` good for  C++ imho! C++ makes a clear distinction between `string` and `shared_ptr<string>` so `string`-typed variables can only contain strings. I know the Java designers purposely made `String` nullable, which modern languages don't do! There is a reason C# changed! I am curious to see which languages followed Java's lead allowing `null` to implicitly be a member of types whose names do not indicate optionality or nullability. I don't think it is common. Explicit `?` or `|null` or ptr types seem more common, perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure how familiar you are with Java but have you noticed that the exception for trying to dereference a null is: Null**Pointer**Exception?  In Java, per the JLS, 'the value of a reference is a pointer' and when you assign null to a variable, you are setting its pointer value to null.  Maybe I spent too many years writing Java, but I don't think of null as being a member of any type.  It's simply the value signifying a pointer to nothing.

Comment: I think the wording of the question's title should be a little bit different: "Is there a programming language other than Java and C# which includes null with its static object types?". In the current form, it reads like a "list-of-things" question at a first glance, and such questions are at risk to be closed with the "needs more focus" reason.

Comment: @DocBrown Thank you for helping me improve the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first say a few words how I understand the question: dynamic typing doesn't count, though any dynamically typed variable - regardless of the type it holds before - can be set to null or None. But the variables themselve don't have a type assigned with them, assigning null to them simply changes the type of their content.

That means your question is about languages which allow static typing, and the inclusion of `null` in those static types, which means that variables which are declared as some object type will be allowed to hold null by default (without having to add some special modifier to the type name, like "*", "&" or "?").

The only language family apart from Java and C# I know where the "standard static object types" automatically include an equivalent of null is the Visual Basic familiy, which includes **(classic) Visual Basic**, **VBA)** and **VB.Net**. The equivalent of null is `Nothing` in this case.

In VBA or VB6, for example, this is correct code:

```
Dim x As New Collection
Set x = Nothing
```

It does not work for strings, however, since `String` is not an object type in VB6/VBA (it is in VB.Net).

There may be more such languages, but I am currently not aware of any them - there are surely people here in the community which have a far greater knowledge of different languages than me, maybe someone of them has another idea.

BTW, I agree that the availability of `null` is not a question of "reference types" vs. "value types". For example, in modern C# (version >=10), you can have all 4 combinations: reference types with and without null, and value types with and without null.

Comment: Scala allows "null references by default". I think people would probably like it if it didn't, but you sort of have to if you want efficient interop with Java libraries.

Answer (score 5):

The author refers to the types of object **pointers** or **references**. In C++, any pointer can be NULL, e.g. `Foo*` is either a pointer to a `Foo` object *or* `NULL`. Similarly in Java, any object reference can be `null`.

This is a giant hole in the type system. You would expect a static type system to ensure that a variable declared with the type `Foo*` would be guaranteed to hold a pointer to an object of type `Foo`. But actually, it might also be a special value that is not a pointer at all, and which will crash your program if you dereference it.

The phrasing in the quote might be ambiguous when coming from a C++ mindset where there is a distinction between an object type and a pointer type. But the quote uses Java terminology where there is no distinction since object types are always reference types. The issue is exactly the same with object pointers in C++ though.

Of course, sometimes you do need an "optional" pointer, for example in a linked list. The problem is not the existence of nulls per se, the problem is it is invisible to the type system whether a pointer may be null or not.

The issue affects a whole bunch of Algol-inspired languages. According to the StackOverflow survey, the most used statically typed languages are TypeScript, Java, C#, C++, C, and Go, and all of them except TypeScript have this issue. So it is fair to say this problem is quite prevalent.

As you note, dynamically typed languages do not really have the problem, since they don't provide any static guarantees in the first place. And statically typed functional languages of the ML-lineage tend to have Option-types which are explicit in the type system.

Languages designed within the last 20 years tend to include null-safety. For example Rust, Kotlin, newer versions of C# (which have it as an opt-in feature), and Swift. I believe Go still have the issue, but while Go is a relatively new language, it is deliberately conservative in its design, for better of worse.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, there are variables of class type, used as local, static or global variables or as parameters, and there are dynamically allocated values of class type, referenced by a pointer which can be null, or by a reference which by language rules must never be null.

In Swift, you have reference types,  that is dynamically allocated objects, referenced by a reference which must never be null, and value types which are local, static or global variables or parameters, or fields of another reference or value type. All of them are never null.

And then you have enum types, which have a tag like C++ enums, and a different associated value for each different value of the tag. One such enum has a tag “none” with no associated value, and a tag “some” with some value. And there’s a lot of syntactic sugar that lets you use this enum as an “optional”.

Whatever type T you have, you can create an enum value of type “optional T”. If you have a variable of type “optional T”, you can assign nil, compare with nil, compare with another value of type T or optional T with well defined rules how nil and non-nil compare.

The word “nil” on its own has type “nil literal” and can be used in many places automatically converted to the appropriate thing.

What you can’t do: Assign nil to a variable of type String, only to one of type optional String. String itself can never be nil, optional String can.

The compiler uses an optimisation where for types where all bits zero is not a legal value, all bits zero is used to store nil for the optional type. So optional string takes 64 bit (String can never be all bits zero) but optional Int64 uses 65 bits.